# How to use UriComponentsBuilder in non-servlet environment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The docs state that if I'm not within a servlet calling thread, but still want to make use of `UriComponentsBuilder` (eg in a batch import), I could use `ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()`.

@see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-uri-building

I tried as follows from the docs:

```
public String createUrl() {
    UriComponentsBuilder base = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/en");
    MvcUriComponentsBuilder builder = MvcUriComponentsBuilder.relativeTo(base);
    builder.withMethodCall(on(BookingController.class).getBooking(21)).buildAndExpand(42);

    URI uri = uriComponents.encode().toUri();
    return uri.toString();
}
```

For testing a non-servlet call:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    builder.createUrl();
}
```

But always getting the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find current request via RequestContextHolder
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder.getCurrentRequest(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.java:190) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.java:158) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
```

So what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you mentioned clearly stated that the static methods are for use in a Servlet environment:

> In a **Servlet environment** the ServletUriComponentsBuilder sub-class
>   provides static factory methods [...]

So if you're not in said Servlet environment, you need to use plain UriComponentsBuilder:

```
UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().scheme("http").host("example.com")
```

Which would fit into your code as

```
public String createUrl() {
    UriComponentsBuilder base = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().scheme("http").host("example.com").path("/en");
    MvcUriComponentsBuilder builder = MvcUriComponentsBuilder.relativeTo(base);
    builder.withMethodCall(on(BookingController.class).getBooking(21)).buildAndExpand(42);

    URI uri = uriComponents.encode().toUri();
    return uri.toString();
}
```

The reason behind this is that in a servlet environment you can get access to scheme and host and context path by querying the Servlet / ServletContext and so on. Running outside of a webapp, this information (scheme, host, context path) need to come from someplace else.

Comment: OK then I think the docs are misleading here. Because I thought the following statement states being able to use the lookup *outside* a servlet context: `For example you may be outside the context of a request (e.g. a batch process that prepares links) [...] For such cases you can use the static "fromXxx" overloaded methods [...]`, following the example I added above.

Comment: No, unfortunately that's only "outside a request" but not "outside of the web container".

Comment: But where is the difference? The code example above where I'm using `@PostConstruct` is  - to my understanding - within the web container, as I'm running this as war on the tomcat. But not in context of the request, as it is not run during a servlet req. I don't get the difference for this case beteween "outside request" and "outside web container". Because both types are triggered without any servlet request?

Comment: You're right. Seems as the documentation should read "only inside a request" as all static methods use RequestContextHolder internally as it seems.